# Python Generics AttributeError

Tags: python, generics, inheritance

I am trying to understand why the following code fails with an Attribute Error.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, ClassVar


T = TypeVar('T', bound='Base')


class Base:

    @classmethod
    def display(cls: Type[T]):
        pass


class A(Base):

    @classmethod
    def display(cls):
        print('A')


class B(Base):

    @classmethod
    def display(cls):
        print('B')


class Class(Generic[T]):
    V = ClassVar[T]

    @classmethod
    def display(cls):
        cls.V.display()


Class[A].display()  # Fails with AttributeError
Class[B].display()
```

I've been reading about generics and I'm confused about what the problem could be. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 36, in <module>
    Class[A].display()
  File "basic.py", line 33, in display
    cls.V.display()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 983, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.__origin__, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 375, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: display
```

Basically, I only need type information in this entire script so a solution involving instantiating objects shouldn't be required as all my methods are static.

Comment: `cls.V` is `ClassVar[T]`. Why would `ClassVar[T]` have a `display` attribute?

Comment: IDK. How do I fix it?